# React app - Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get an authentication in place for a react app that I am building.. Given below is the code I have for my App.js and Auth.js files

When I load my app it says

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Can someone assist on where I could be going wrong here, thanks

**Code for App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import SideBar from "./components/Sidebar/SideBar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";
import Report1 from "./pages/Report1";
import Report2 from "./pages/Report2";
import Auth from "./components/Auth";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";



function App() {
  const authToken = false;
  return (
    <div>
      {!authToken && <Auth />}
      {authToken && (
      <Router>
      <SideBar>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="/Report1" element={<Report1 />} />
          <Route path="/Report2" element={<Report2 />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<> not found</>} />
        </Routes>
      </SideBar>
    </Router>
  )}
</div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

**Code for Auth.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Auth = () => {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const viewLogin = (status) => {
  setError(null);
  setIsLogin(status);
  };

  return (
    <div className="auth-container">
      <div className="auth-container-box">
        <form>
          <h2>{isLogin ? "Please log in" : "Please sign up"}</h2>
          <input type="email" placeholder="email" />
          <input type="password" placeholder="password" />

          {!isLogin && <input type="password" placeholder="confirm pass" />}
          <input type="submit" className="create" />
          {error && <p>{error}</p>}
        </form>

        <div className="auth-options">
          <button
            onClick={viewLogin(false)}
          >
            Sign up
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={viewLogin(true)}
          >
            Login
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Auth;
```

Answer (score 2):

These 2 are the culprit:

`onClick={viewLogin(false)}` and  `onClick={viewLogin(true)}`

I'm assuming you wrote this thinking how it works in [normal HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp). However, this is JSX and writing `onClick={funcName()}` will actually call the function right then when the component renders. What we want to do is give it a function that will be called later when the `onClick` event happens.

The simple fix:
 `onClick={()=> viewLogin(false)}` and  `onClick={()=> viewLogin(true)}`

Answer (score 1):

You directly called the functions in your buttons, which will lead to new renders during the rendering phase.

You should switch

```
<button onClick={viewLogin(false)}>
```

with

```
<button onClick={() => viewLogin(false)}>
```

This way you pass an actual function to the button which will be executed on click and not right away.

Answer (score 1):

The issue causing the "Too many re-renders" error is in the onClick handlers of the buttons in your Auth.js component. When using onClick handlers, you should pass a function reference, but in your code, you are directly invoking the functions, which causes an infinite loop of re-renders.

Corrected code for Auth.js:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Auth = () => {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const viewLogin = (status) => {
    setError(null);
    setIsLogin(status);
  };

  return (
    <div className="auth-container">
      <div className="auth-container-box">
        <form>
          <h2>{isLogin ? "Please log in" : "Please sign up"}</h2>
          <input type="email" placeholder="email" />
          <input type="password" placeholder="password" />

          {!isLogin && <input type="password" placeholder="confirm pass" />}
          <input type="submit" className="create" />
          {error && <p>{error}</p>}
        </form>

        <div className="auth-options">
          {/* Use arrow functions or bind() to pass function references */}
          <button onClick={() => viewLogin(false)}>Sign up</button>
          <button onClick={() => viewLogin(true)}>Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Auth;
```

Comment: did any part of this answer come from chatgpt?